# XAML Binding: Combobox populating textbox in one scenario, but not another? WPF

Tags: wpf, database, xaml, binding, combobox

I have one set of code working properly. It loads the "address" field from a database of user records containing stuff like [ID, Fname, Lname, address, zip, etc] into a ComboBox's selection set. Once a user selects an address it displays that selection in a corresponding textbox as well.

**working code:**

```
<Window x:Class="CC_Ticketing_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CC_Ticketing_WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="orderheaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=address}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- I think this what you said populated properly in the comments -->
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" DataContext="{StaticResource orderheaderDataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader}" DisplayMemberPath="address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"/>
        <!-- this should replicate what you see in the combobox -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The problem is I know that's very limited as it relies on defining everything in the stack panel. I am trying this something along these lines instead:

**broken code**

```
<Window x:Class="CC_Ticketing_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CC_Ticketing_WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="orderheaderTemplate">
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" DataContext="{StaticResource orderheaderDataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/dataroot/orderheader}" DisplayMemberPath="address" SelectedValuePath="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding ElementName=cb_Address,Path=SelectedValue,Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This loads the addresses and allows selection in the combobox, but sends nothing to the textbox.  Eventually I'd want selecting an address from this combox to not only send the selection to the textbox, but also send the other relevant data from that record to other textbox's (like you select just an address and it populates a bunch of textboxes with the address, name, zip, etc.) Pretty common business need. Could someone put me on the right track here to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I made and it works.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb_Address" DisplayMemberPath="address" SelectedValuePath="content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEditable="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address" Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cb_Address, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Code behind to test it

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<OrderHeader> Data = new ObservableCollection<OrderHeader>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Data.Add(new OrderHeader { address = "Address_" + i.ToString(), content = "Content_"+i.ToString() });
        }

        cb_Address.ItemsSource = Data;
    }

    public class OrderHeader
    {
        public string address {  get; set;}
        public string content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that from scratch is throwing me the exception: The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection<OrderHeader>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add "using System.Collections.ObjectModel;"

Comment: Reading around it looks like I might be missing an assembly reference? I'm new enough to be thrown by that but I'm researching how to reference it now.

Comment: ;) no problem. We all went that road.

Comment: ahhh gotcha, that does work!  Could I ask for an additional edit of what it would look like for a combobox selection to populate a second combobox and textbox (Example: combox 1 holds first names, combox 2 holds last names. When you select a first name it would not only fill its firstname textbox but additionally fill combobox 2 and textbox 2 with their correct last names).  If that's too much no worries and I'll checkmark it as solved anyway.  Thanks much Ismail!

Answer (score 1):

Change Path on the textbox to SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.Content

Comment: Negatory, that still does not send.

Comment: Wait, i'll try it here. 1 moment please.

Comment: Do you have any sample dat I can paste in?

Comment: Not really unfortunately, all my data is in a big xml file and it's real user data.  (I also updated my working and broken code, for some reason it wasn't listing some of the declarations)

Comment: The broken code appears to work if I just change Path=SelectedValue to Path=Text, but I'm not seeing why SelectedValue or SelectedItem.Content  breaks it

Answer (score 1):

You can, simply bind the code below with the right combobox.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tb_Address">
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cb_Firstnames, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Run Text=" " />
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cb_Lastnames, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
```